# android ndk External Native Build Issues

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

> External Native Build Issues
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing 'C:\Users\SHIDHIN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\SHIDHIN\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\SHIDHIN\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/SHIDHIN/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\SHIDHIN\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -n}
>   md "C:\Users\SHIDHIN\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\debug\obj\local\x86\objs\tmessages.27.\opus\src" >NUL 2>NUL || rem
>
> Error:executing external native build for ndkBuild C:\Users\SHIDHIN\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I  download the telegram source code from github I am getting this errors while trying to open the project in android studio

Comment: have anyone solved this error?